# Lost volume when run docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I had running container with wordpress and other container with MySQL and its volume (see config below). Then I've run `docker-compose up -d --build` and then I see wordpress installation page, that means empty database. Also I could kill some docker process before that, don't remember exactly which by command ```sudo kill -9 [process_id].

Where can I find solution to restore my volume with all the information this has?

```
services:
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
        - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
        - wordpress_files:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: my_wordpress_db_password

   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_db_root_password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_wordpress_db_password
volumes:
    wordpress_files:
    db_data:
    uploads.ini:
```

Comment: docker-compose does not delete volumes unless you run `docker-compose down` with the `-v` flag. What is the output of `docker volume ls`? (please update your question with this information rather than answering in a comment)

Comment: Also, what does `docker ps -a` show, and did you run docker-compose from a different directory name?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the output of "docker volume ls". If you were using the container only with the docker run command and now switched to compose, maybe you when you runned docker-compose up Docker created a new empty volume called db_db_data.